# continuous Ajax calls until expected response is met

Tags: jquery, ajax, recursion

I've been working on an ajax call that needs to be called repeatedly until I get a response. Example scenario is: the `User` is notified when an `Admin` posts something.

I did something like this, but it doesn't work well.

```
function posts() {
  $.ajax
  ({
   type: "GET",
   url: "http://mywebsite.csit.ph/process/new_posts.php",
   data: "user="+user,
   success: function(){
   if(data){  //if new_posts.php echo something.
     //do task here
   }else{
     posts();  //calling the ajax again.
   }
   },
   error: function(){
    posts();  //calling the ajax again.
   }
  });
}
```

the `posts()` function needs to be called until a response is received.

Comment: use while loop in backend for the reply.. and call ajax only once

Comment: @chiragsatapara tried while in my php for the reply and make 1 ajax call as you suggest but it still not go on success state with data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/GRMule/WQXXT/

I copied your code run on JS FIddle without data, I tested the negative scenario wherein you are calling posts() again and again. It works.

```
function posts() {
    $.ajax
        ({
            type: "GET",
            url:'/echo/js/?js=hello%20world!',
            success: function(){
            if(data){  //if new_posts.php echo something.
                //do task here
                $('#output').html('Data acheived: there was an error!');
            }else{
                posts();  //calling the ajax again.
            }
        },
        error: function(){
            $('#output').html('Bummer: there was an error!');
            posts();  //calling the ajax again.
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks your code helped me to accomplish something similar. I needed to fetch the data continuously page by page until I have everything possible